# Arraylist indexing

Tags: java, android, arrays

so we have an object which includes an x coordinate and we're trying to find which object saved in our arraylist "save" in closest to a view whose coordinates are from getLocationInWindow() which are saved into an array.

```
for (int i=0; i<save.size(); i++){
    if(save.get(i).getxPosition() == arr2[0]){
        index = i;
     }
}
```

However this code always returns the index of the final element, no matter what. Does anybody have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I assume this will be a lot of help to other people facing this issue but we were finally able to solve this after moving a variable to declare it as a global variable.